# Stacked divs resizing each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

This is probably going to be a long one:
I'm trying to make a chat application (similar to Slack) with Electron, React and Socket.io. My issue is mostly dealing with React and CSS/Sass though. Right now I've got a few bootstrap, but I'm not really using the grid system at all, so that can/may be scrapped.

The structure of the page is as follows: I've got a footer with a resizable textarea. above it I've got a div that will be holding messages. That div has overflow-y set to scroll, that way the scrollbar is only for the messages and doesn't take the entire page's space. I want the div to get shorter as the footer grows with the textarea. Right now though the div just extends under the footer (and the scrollbar along with it). Since  the messages fill the div there's nothing to scroll and no thumb (I think that's the correct term) in the scrollbar.

React component (I've only included one li for the sake of brevity, but in my code I've got bunch):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, Media, Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props;
  }

  footerResize() {
    // code to resize messages div, or at least get some information about
    // the footer's height
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <div className="sidebar">
        </div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div classname="messages">
            <ul>
              <li className="message>
                <Media>
                  <Media.Left>
                    <Image src="#" />
                  </Media.Left>
                  <Media.Body>
                    <Media.Heading>
                      Name
                    </Media.Heading>
                    Message content
                  </Media.Body>
                </Media>
              <li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <footer>
            <textarea defaultValue="test text" />
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

_page.scss (most of this is from the file name _page.scss but a few properties are pulled in from other files here so I'm only typing one file's contents):

```
$dark-grey: #383838;
$default-font-color: #FFFFFF;
$light-grey: #474747;
$light-light-grey: #908E8F
$sidebar-width: 250px;

body {
  color: $default-font-color;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.page {
  background-color: $light-grey;
  height: 100vh;
  .sidebar {
    background-color: $light-light-grey;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: $sidebar-width;
    .container-fluid {
      margin-left: $sidebar-width;
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      .messages {
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      footer {
        background-color: $main-green;
        bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        width: calc(100% - #{$sidebar-width});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different things to get this to work. I've tried a few node modules. I've tried adding event listeners both by adding `ref='footer'` to the footer and referring to it as `this.refs.footer` in when adding the event listener and by giving footer and id and using `document.getElementById('footer')`. The whatever I try I can't get any information about the footer's size in the footerResize. Any help on this would be appreciated. I don't even know if this is something I should be doing with sass properties or whether I need js/React to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out a flexbox based layout.

This for `.container-fluid`

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

This for `.messages`

```
flex: 1;
```

Then you remove `position: fixed` from `footer`

What this does: it sets the height of `.messages` to fill its parent's remaining space. So when `footer` gets bigger, there is less remaining space and `.messages` will shrink.

Please note that you will need to add vendor prefixes for flexbox depending on your targeted browser support.

Comment: Thanks I'll take look into that and see if it works.